# NEW Array Search SUM in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array structure which is something like

```
$a = array("100","200","350"); 
$b = 400; // Is not a array is the finding value;
```

I want to find 400 sum from array which means 400 is a value is the sum of 100+200+100(350-100) then return array will be

`$z = array("0","0","250");`

Is that possible?

Comment: Uhm...I really don't understand the question. But it seems do-able with PHP. At least from what I can sort of understand from your question.

Comment: Rephrase your q. I can't understand how you want to get from 
("100","200","350") to ("0","0","250") by applying/comparing 400. 100+200+100(350-100)  makes no sense in this context.

Comment: You can just iterate over the input array, then substract `$b` or `min($b, $in_a)` from each, until `$b` becomes zero. Use a `foreach` with array `&$v` value reference for simplicity.

Comment: Ough, is it 400-100=300->300-200=100->100-350=-250 (not 250)? Sure, with custom code.

Comment: I cleaned up your question a bit, but consider adding a bit more details to clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$a = array("100","200","350"); 
$b = 400; // Is not a array is the finding value;

$left = $b;
$new_array = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++)
{
    $new_value[] = max($a[$i]-$left, 0);
    $left = max($left - $a[$i], 0);
}

var_dump($new_value);
```

http://3v4l.org/d87rs

Answer (score 0):

array_walk might be a good choice for this. Use references so you won't have to use extra memory. Makes it better if you have bigger size data.

```
<?php

//init
$a = array("100","200","350");
$b = 400; 

//walk the array. Pass by reference.
array_walk($a, function(&$item) use (&$b){
    $tmpItem = $item;
    $item = (($b-$item)>0)?0:$item-$b;
    $b-=$tmpItem;
});

//debug
print_r($a);
```

?>

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 250
)
```

Answer (score 0):

While [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) seems to be the best tool for the job, I prefer to not modify the original array but generate a new one.

For this approach, [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) is one of the ways to go:

```
$a = array("100","200","350");
$b = 400;

$z = array_reduce(
    $a,                               // process $a
    function(array $carry, $item) use (& $b) {
        // Cannot subtract from $item more than its value
        $sub = min($item, $b);
        // Subtract from $item and put it into the result array
        $item   -= $sub;
        $carry[] = $item;
        // Update the remainder
        $b -= $sub;
        // Return the partial result
        return $carry;
    },
    array()                           // start with an empty list
);
```

After the code runs, `$z` contains the required list of values and `$b` contains the remainder. If `$b` is greater than `0` then all the values in `$z` are `0` and `$b` contains the difference between `$b` and `array_sum($a)`. If `$b` is `0` then the values in `$a` were big enough to cover it and the values returned in `$z` are the remainder.